# Big O of recursive functions with multiple function calls?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having trouble determining the worst case time complexity of this recursive function:

```
long f(int n) {
  if(n <= 0) return 1;
  else {
    return f(n / 2) + f(n / 2) + f(n / 2);
  }
}
```

I understand that if you were just returning f(n / 2) once, it would be O(log n). So I was wondering if having it three, four, five, etc times would affect the function's big O. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying by a constant *never* affects the complexity.  Of course, the execution time is roughly tripled, but the issue is how the time increases with respect to the value of **n**, not what the clock says.

Do note that this applies so easily because you're calling the same function with the same value; this could be reliably replaced by

```
return 3 * f(n/2)
```

If you had three *different* calls, such as

```
return f(n/2) + f(int(sqrt(n)) + f(n-1)
```

... then you'd have to compute the complexity of each and consider only the most complex.  That isn't hard with this function; however, with a more complex function, such as the Collatz sequence, you'd have a more difficult time considering all of the 2nd- and 3rd-order complexities.  You would also have more trouble with a call to an indirectly recursive function, such as

```
long f(int n);

long g(int n) {
  if(n <= 2) return 1;
  else {
    return f(n*n mod 10) + g(n-2);
  }
}

long f(int n) {
  if(n <= 0) return 1;
  else {
    return f(n / 2) + g(n / 2);
  }
}
```

Bottom line: *your* question is simple, but beware of follow-up questions.